# Javascript-loaded content not pushing height of container?

Tags: javascript, css, disqus

I've exhausted my understanding of CSS and JS while tackling this issue.

On this website: http://glorydayssports.net/blog/featured-game-dodging-bullets-vs-cash-paid-dodgeball

When the Disqus comments load below, they do not push down their container. This happens in Safari and Chrome, but looks just fine in Firefox and acts as I imagined it would. I contacted Disqus about it and they said that it's possible I have JavaScript somewhere on the page that is not allowing the height to expand, but I've tried disabling all the other JS except for Disqus and it still occurs.

Has anyone seen this happen before? None of the container elements have a fixed height on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `div#dsq-content` a `height: auto;`. Currently it's using `.clearfix`'s height of `1px`.

Comment: No problem. You may also want to look into that 1px height defined for your `.clearfix` elements, as it might cause you similar grief in the future if applied to other elements whose height should be based on their content.